# getchar() causes error while scanf don't

Tags: c, scanf, getchar

```
#include<stdio.h>
void main() {
char ch;
ch=getchar();
printf("%d",ch);
}
```

This gives me error NZEC (non zero exit code) but when I use-

```
#include<stdio.h>
void main() {
char ch;
scanf("%c",&ch);
printf("%d",ch);
}
```

No execution error and accepts solution
What's wrong with getchar() ?

I am quite new to C so don't know much I checked few answers on difference between scanf and getchar but I could not understand. Please help me in understanding this behaviour.

**Solution:**
I did not know that my query is related to this question:
[What should main() return in C and C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/204476/what-should-main-return-in-c-and-c)

Moreover both of these are working-

```
#include<stdio.h>
void main() {
int ch;
ch=getchar();
printf("%d",ch);
}
```

changing `char` to `int` and-

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(void) {
char ch;
ch=getchar();
printf("%d",ch);
return 0;
}
```

changing `void` to `int`

Comment: The `main` function is supposed to be declared to return an `int`. It's part of the C specification. Not doing that leads to [*undefined behavior*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). See e.g. [this `main` function reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/main_function) for more information.

Comment: *This gives me error NZEC (non zero exit code)* Thats what you get with `void main()`

Comment: did you happen to get any warning from the compiler?

Comment: I ran this on online judge for hacker earth ...there I got execution error but the code compiled succesfully.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both are undefined behaviours because `main` should return `int` as defined by the C standard. It's especially important when you are checking its return code.

Change the definition to:

```
int main(void)
{
    ...
}
```

Note that since [C99](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C99), `main` doesn't need to explicitly return any value. It's as if you had `return 0;` at the end. But if you are using C89, you are required to return a value explicitly (or call `exit`).

Comment: it worked by this as well as by changing `char ch` to `int ch` as suggested by @user3121023 

One more question @usr since I am learning c which standard should I use and how do I actually learn it any good sources if u can recommend so that someday I could answer like you thanks!

Comment: Try to use the latest standard C11 if you can (but support/use of C11 is not widespread). Otherwise, I'd suggest to follow C99.

Comment: any good sources for c learning that u wud like to recommend

Comment: K&R 2nd edition is good for exercises (bit the book itself is outdated). I heard "C Programming: A Modern Approach" is quite good (covers c99). But depending your level, you might also like "C How to Program (8th Edition)" too. But others may different opinions. You can search and read about (the quality of) others textbooks.

Answer (score 1):

Your `main()` should returns `int` instead of `void` As its specified in `n1570` standard

> It shall be defined with a return type of int and with no parameters:
>   int main(void) { /* ... */ }

Replace error code blocks as

```
int  main() {
        char ch;
        ch=getchar();
        printf("%d",ch);
        return 0;
}
```